# Trying to append a group of files with date; my script amends the file type instead!

Tags: linux, shell, find, filenames, mv

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$0" "$0"-$(date +%Y%m%d)' {} \;
```

I'm so close to getting this script to work for a daily group of csv files. Instead of adding the date to the end of the file, it adds the date to the FILE TYPE (.csv -> .csv-10-02-2020. Is maxdepth the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to insert the date before the dot, so you need to split the name:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.*' -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$0" "${0%.*}"-$(date +%Y%m%d).${0##*.}' {} \;
```

`${0%.*}` takes the name up to the `.` and `${0##*.}` gives you the extension (with the date in between).

`-maxdepth 1` limits the files to the current directory (excluding subdirectories).

Comment: @steeldriver you are right. I've added `-name '*.*'` as a workaround

Comment: That's a reasonable fix I think (I couldn't come up with anything better)